# How to implement sharing case for multiple case with different content?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I got a switch statement and "BMW" and "Mercedes" cases sharing almost same content with little difference(update methods).

I don't want to repeat all code for these cases content's. Is there any way to handle this problem?

```
switch (car) {

  case "BMW":
    updateBmwSpecs();
    ...//Same code with Mercedes case
    break;

  case "Mercedes":
    updateMercedesSpecs();
    ...//Same code with BMW case
    break;

  case "Ferrari":
    //content
    break;

  ...//Remaining cases
}
```

Comment: Place the shared code in some method?

Comment: Put them in a method?

Comment: what about a private method with the common code? May sound trivial, but it could be an option. If there is anything more specific, could you provide us with a little more context?

Comment: Same `case` for both with an `if/else` inside?

Comment: @tobias_k if there are more cases with common code the `if/else` could grow too much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any further information, the only option I see here would be to extract a helper method with that common functionality:

```
switch (car) {
    case "BMW":
        updateBmwSpecs();
        doCommon();
        break;

    case "Mercedes":
        updateMercedesSpecs();
        doCommon();
        break;

    case "Ferrari":
        break;

    // remaining cases
}

private void doCommon() {
    // do whatever logic be common to BMW and Mercedes
    // e.g. take joy rides through the city and get too many car washes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems almost too trivial to mention, but you could just have the same `case` for both and add an `if/else` within that case to determine which method to call.

```
switch (car) {
    case "BMW":
    case "Mercedes":
        if (car.equals("BMW")) {
            updateBmwSpecs();
        } else {
            updateMercedesSpecs();
        }
        ...//Same code for Mercedes and BMW case
        break;

    ...//Remaining cases
}
```

Or add a parameter for the car type to the `updateSpecs` method?

```
switch (car) {
    case "BMW":
    case "Mercedes":
        updateCarSpecs(car);
        ...//Same code for Mercedes and BMW case
        break;

    ...//Remaining cases
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of having a case then?  You could remove it and it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Nexevis What do you mean? There are still the other cases, for Ferrari etc., not shown as they are not relevant here. Of course, you could do the same with just a large number of `if/else if/else`, but a `switch/case` still seems a lot cleaner, even if there's a single `if/else` inside. Of course, it depends. If this is needed for _each_, or at least for a significant number of the cases, then there are certainly better options.

Comment: In my opinion, using a `switch` is to make very clear what is operating for each condition, but putting this `if else` makes it very confusing to read and kind of the defeats the purpose of using a `switch` statement to begin with.  Obviously this _works_ but I don't think it would be good practice to do it like this.  This also restricts you having `BMW` and `Mercedes` next to each other or else the code breaks.  What if a 3rd car needs to use the similar code as well in the future?

Comment: @Nexevis I guess that's a matter of opinion. I agree that it's a bit messy, but IMHO it's stil clearer than either the repeated code or having to look up what that private method does. Also, what if the method has to modify local variables? Or if there is a third case that needs _part_ of the common code? I do not say that this is perfect in all situations, but it's an alternative that should be considered.